# Is $PAP$ invertible if $P$ is a projection operator and $A$ is arbitrary?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $P \neq I$ be a projection operator in a hilbert space, that is $P^2 = P$.
Does there exist an operator $A$ such that $PAP$ is invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}$ No, since $\Ima PAP \subseteq \Ima P \subsetneq H$ so $PAP$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: The assumption was $P \ne I$.

Answer (score 1):

If $P\equiv 0$ then for any $A$ we have $PAP\equiv 0$ hence such $A$ need not tu exist.